# Word to PDF : Custom Page applies only partial background color

Tags: pdf, ms-word, background-color

What am I doing ?

1. I am creating my own PDF templates for my Tablets for tracking.
2. **I must have of custom page setup to accommodate my designs.**
3. These PDF templates then I import in my notes taking app.
4. I need to have a background color other than white.

Issue is with background color (**how to fix this ?**)

1. to fit my design, I have to use a custom page setup, 23cm W and 31cm H. When I export to PDF (either Save As or Print), the background color is not applied on the whole PDF document. It keeps it White bg color, in a mirrored L shaped in the PDF document. The other part is the bg color I had chosen.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a programming issue you set the Word page size apply a Word background colour and export to PDF, these are all user settings and choices. The real big problem is that should be well under 1 KB and Ms Word uses 182 KB  to show one single colour paper with nothing on it!

[image]